# Proof that a function involving power sets and unions is bijective

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be two non-empty sets and $A \cap B \neq \varnothing$. Let $f : P(A) \longrightarrow P(A \cap B)$ be defined by $f(X) = X \cap B$. Is $f$ a function? Is it a bijective function? Give proofs.

It is clearly a function since all sets are distinct and unique; but i dont know how to put it in a rigorous format. And it should be surjective but not injective but I tried to use subsets and elements of power set and dont know where to go from there.

Comment: What does A ∩ B 6= ∅ mean ?

Comment: 6= is a not equal sign my bad

Comment: Note that $A\cap B \subseteq A$. So for any subset $C \subseteq A \cap B, C \subseteq A$. Use this to show surjectivity. For *not* injective, look for $A, A\cap B \in P(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

I will provide some guidance but not a full explicit proof.

To show that $f$ is a function you do not only need to show that $f(X)$ is uniquely determined, but also that $f(X)$ is actually inside the range of the function. In this case: Show **$f(X) = X\cap B \in P(A\cap B)$ **.

To show that $f$ is surjective. Let $C\in P(A\cap B)$ and find a $X\in P(A)$ such that $f(X) = C$. Note here that since $C$. Note that $C\in P(A\cap B)$ implies that $C\subseteq A\cap B$, thus $C\subseteq A$. Can you solve it from here?

To show that $f$ is not injective. Experiment around. What happens when you try a couple of different sets $A$ and $B$? How will the function look? You dont have to do a lot here to find sets $A$ and $B$ so that the function is clearly not injective.

Answer (score 0):

(I). $f$ is surjective. For if $Y\subset A\cap B$ then $Y=Y\cap (A\cap B)$ so $$f(Y)=Y\cap B=(Y\cap (A\cap B))\cap B=$$ $$=Y\cap ((A\cap B)\cap B)=$$ $$=Y\cap (A\cap (B\cap B))=$$ $$=Y\cap (A\cap B)=Y.$$

(II). If $A$ is not a subset of $B$ then $f(A$ \ $B)=f(\phi)=\phi$ but $A$ \ $B \ne \phi$ so $f$ is not injective, and a fortiori, not bijective.

(III). If $A\subset B$ then $A\cap B=A$ and $f$ is bijective. For if $X\subset A$ then $X=X\cap A$ so  $$f(X)=X\cap B=(X\cap A)\cap B=$$ $$=X\cap (A\cap B)=X\cap A=X,$$ so $f$ is injective, and by (I), $f$ is also surjective.